# LED not glowing

Tags: arduino, iot

I a beginner to IoT. I want to glow LED connected to arduino for this I have made connections as described below, also see the image of breadboard attached here.
[LED Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZXh4.jpg)
Connected
Arduino GND to one leg of LED and 3.3V to another leg of LED.
My Arduino program is-

```
   void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);

     // connect to wifi.
      WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
      Serial.print("connecting");
      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
         Serial.print(".");
         delay(500);
      }
      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("connected: ");
      Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  
      Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
      Firebase.set("LED_STATUS",0);
   }

   int n = 0;

   void loop() {
  // get value
      n = Firebase.getInt("LED_STATIS");
 
      if (n == 1) {
         Serial.print("LED IS ON");
         digitalWrite(D1,HIGH);      
         return;
     }else{
          Serial.print("LED IS OFF");
          digitalWrite(D1,LOW);      
          return;
       }
       delay(1000);
  }
```

Serial monitor shows LED is ON as shown in screenshot.
[Serial Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfhYO.png)

Comment: If Im not mistaken...the LED pins are to be oriented a particular way...ie current only flow one way...so try and flip the LED around

Comment: ...and it almost looks like one of the led pins is in the wrong hole on the board.

Comment: Check the LED legs. Most probably the longer leg which is meant to be connected to the +ve is connected to the -ve. Flip it around and it should work.

Comment: I would suggest using a resistor to limit the current for the LED... maybe your LED is already dead. I would use a 200Ohm resistor. Maybe the output pin is already broken as well... try using a different pin.

Comment: tried flipping as well but still not glowing

Answer (score 0):

i think you should declare pinMode in setup, and you put LED in D0

```
    #define LED D0            // Led in NodeMCU at pin GPIO16 (D0).
    void setup() {
        pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);    // LED pin as output.
    }

    void loop() {
         if (n == 1) {
             Serial.print("LED IS ON");
             digitalWrite(LED ,HIGH);      
             return;
         }else{
             Serial.print("LED IS OFF");
             digitalWrite(LED ,LOW);      
             return;
         }
    }
```

note that it has built-in LED, but its active low, it should glow when logic is 0
and you should using pull-up resistor, because you can't depend current supply from GPIO pin since its only provide 12mA

Comment: i have tried this as well but my led is not glowing

Comment: is bulit-in led glowing?

Comment: are u referring to Arduino LED? if so yes it is glowing when running the program.